# How to cut substring between known characters in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I cut substring between two known character sequences in SQL Server?

For example: This is my string (column in a table)

> 'DateTimeFormat=dd.MM.yyyy&ReportDate_FromDate=08/11/2014 00:00:00&ReportDate_ToDate=08/12/2014 23:59:00&Reports_Brand:isnull=true&Reports_Portal:isnull=true&Reports_Currency:isnull=true&ReportBy=WEEK&OrderBy:isnull=true&IncludeDataForLastHour:isnull=true&ServerName:isnull=true&User=pirman1&Reports_Export=False&Internal'

and I want to see only `pirman1` which is between `&User=` and the following `&`.

Comment: Do it in your front end ....

Comment: what you mean by 'your front end' ?

Comment: In your application - C#, VB.NET, PHP, Ruby - whatever you use. This is not a good job for T-SQL (which is rather weak when it comes to string manipulation) ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested this code, with a slight alteration to Mureinik's code, this one works fine.

```
 SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(string, start_pos,  end_pos - start_pos  
    +1), '&User=', ''), '&', '')

   FROM   (SELECT string,
           CHARINDEX('&User=', string) AS start_pos, 
           CHARINDEX('&', string, CHARINDEX('&User=', string)+1)  AS end_pos
           FROM dbo.TestTbl
      ) AS abc
```

Answer (score 0):

A combination of [`substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) and [`charindex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) should do the trick:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(str_col, start_pos, end_pos - start_pos + 1)
FROM   (SELECT str_col,
               CHARINDEX('&User=', str_col) AS start_pos, 
               CHARINDEX('&', str_col, CHARINDEX('&User=', str_col) + 1) AS end_pos
        FROM   my_table) t
```

Comment: This gives me &User=pirman1. How to cut &User=                                                                                     SELECT SUBSTRING([Parameters], start_pos, end_pos - start_pos  )
FROM   (SELECT [Parameters],
               CHARINDEX('&User=', [Parameters]) AS start_pos, 
               CHARINDEX('&', [Parameters], CHARINDEX('&User=', [Parameters]) + 1) AS end_pos
        FROM   table1) t